# In python, list remove acts strangely -- two lests have elements removed

Tags: python, list

```
inC = list(range(6))
outC = list(range(2))
tx = inC
for j in range(0,len(outC)):
    tx.remove(outC[j])
print(inC, outC, tx)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5] [0, 1] [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Notice that inC and tx both have 0 and 1 removed.
Is this the way it is supposed to work?

Comment: Variables hold **references** to objects. You have two variables referencing the same list.

Comment: `tx = inC` create reference, not copy

Comment: After `tx = inC`, both names refer to the same list. If you want a copy, you can do for example `tx = inC[:]`